# Creating directory based on function being run

Tags: python, pytest, playwright, playwright-python

I am using pytest to run some E2E tests for our website, I want to save a video for the actual test that is being run.
Here is the code I have so far:

```
import os
import pytest
import time
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright
from survey import SurveyPage
from utils import setup_video_and_screenshot_dirs


@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def survey_page(request):
    # Get the test name from the request object and extract only the test name
    test_name = os.path.splitext(request.node.name.split("::")[-1])[0]

    # Setup video and screenshot directories based on the test name
    video_dir, screenshot_dir = setup_video_and_screenshot_dirs(test_name)

    # Launch the browser and create a new page with video recording enabled
    with sync_playwright() as playwright:
        browser = playwright.chromium.launch()
        context = browser.new_context(
            record_video_dir=video_dir,
            viewport={'width': 1920, 'height': 1080}
        )
        page = context.new_page()
        page.goto(os.environ['URL'])

        yield SurveyPage(page)

        page.close()
        context.close()
        browser.close()


def test_survey_page_buttons_exist(survey_page):
    # Wait for 2 seconds to ensure page load
    time.sleep(2)
    # survey_page.page.wait_for_load_state('load')

    # Check if "Save & Continue" button exists
    save_and_continue_button_exists = survey_page.page.query_selector(
        '[data-testid="save-1"]') is not None
    assert save_and_continue_button_exists, "Save & Continue button not found on the page"

    # Check if "Skip" button exists
    skip_button_exists = survey_page.page.query_selector(
        '[data-testid="skip-1"]') is not None
    assert skip_button_exists, "Skip button not found on the page"
```

And this is my utils.py

```
import os


def setup_video_and_screenshot_dirs(test_name: str):
    base_dir = os.path.join("/app/reports", test_name)
    video_dir = os.path.join(base_dir, 'video')
    screenshot_dir = os.path.join(base_dir, 'screenshots')

    # Delete existing video files in the directory
    if os.path.exists(video_dir):
        file_list = os.listdir(video_dir)
        for file_name in file_list:
            file_path = os.path.join(video_dir, file_name)
            os.remove(file_path)

    os.makedirs(video_dir, exist_ok=True)

    # Delete existing screenshot files in the directory
    if os.path.exists(screenshot_dir):
        file_list = os.listdir(screenshot_dir)
        for file_name in file_list:
            file_path = os.path.join(screenshot_dir, file_name)
            os.remove(file_path)

    os.makedirs(screenshot_dir, exist_ok=True)

    return video_dir, screenshot_dir
```

When I run the test, the video is being saved in the `/app/reports/test_survey/video` directory, where as I want to save it in the `/app/reports/test_survey_page_buttons_exist/video`

What am I missing?

The only way I can do it is using the RE module, like

```
def survey_page(request):
    # Get the test name from the request object and extract only the test name
    print(f"Request: {request}")
    # Get the test name from the request object using regular expressions
    match = re.search(r"Function (\w+)", str(request))
    if match:
        test_name = match.group(1)
    else:
        raise ValueError("Could not extract test name from request.")
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You are trying to get the test name from a module fixture that runs only once in the test module - that won't work, you will get the name of the test module instead. If you want to use a test-specific fixture, you cannot make it module-scoped.